# Android Lollipop 5.0 Notification Icon Small, Large Bitmap

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I wanted to create a question on how to create notification icons for an app. Then answer it.

I will be answering the following questions that I feel need to be grouped together in one explanation rather than spread across the inter web.

**FIRST**

What is a small icon in notification.builder?

**SECOND**

What is a large icon in notification.builder?

**THIRD**

How do I make a small, large icon for notifications?

Answer (score 1):

**Small Icon** : Icon that will be shown in the status bar when your notification is fired

[image: Small Icon]

**Large Icon** : Icon that will be shown in the notification tray (When slides down). If large icon is missing, then the small icon is used for this purpose.

[image: Large Icon]

Refer [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) for more details.

For creating notification icons, you can use [Notification Icon Generator of Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example)

Answer (score 1):

**1.)**

To answer the first question we need to understand the design guidelines that Google has graciously made for Android.

**[GOOGLE DESIGN GUIDELINES](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)**

Watch the **video** that is located in the above link, in the section shown below. It will explain the design behind android's new notifications

[image]

A **small icon** is basically a context to what the app is trying to convey or it can be used to act as the main icon for all notifications, but know that you will not get a filled in **SMALL ICON** it will always be centered in the circle that is how Google has designed it.

For example I am building an app that will have many different notifications pushed to the user. However, I would like the main app icon to show as a large icon using Bitmap, but to help the users know the context and grow a habit of understanding that notification to be connected with a certain action in the app. The small icon would serve that purpose by providing a simple transparent white image.

A **small icon** is a completely **white** transparent image that has the main components of the graphic transparent to be shown on the notification tray, and when slid down.

**2.)**

Refer to the above link, video for the **large icon** reference.

A **large icon** can be the main app icon, or it can be an image downloaded from a data source. Preferably in my situation I use it as the main app icon. However, it can be anything in Facebook, Instagram use images downloaded from their servers to serve as context for who is commenting on a post, then Facebook uses their small icon to represent Facebook. Focusing on the user, rather than the app.

**3.)**

To make a **small icon** you will need to either consult a graphics designer or follow the icon size guide **[here](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/)**.

For **large icons** that would depend on what you need exactly. Whether you want to use the app icon itself, or make one a bit more larger for example, Music player shows album art in a big size. Possibly using custom layouts.

Lastly, something I also really struggled with for a few days was the context. I kept getting Null Pointer Exception, and the app would crash. What was happening was I was using a fragment. I was passing context properly, however I was getting the context when the fragment was created, "**OnCreate**". This works both in fragments and activities. Those that have this issue in an activity do the same make sure your context is being initialized in the OnCreate.

**mContext = getActivity();** For Fragments

**mContext = MainActivity.this;** For Activities

That is it, let me know if you have any questions or concerns. I am sure that I might be missing some info, or not explaining it entirely as Google would, but I was having tons of trouble so I wanted to make sure those that were struggling as I was could have something to help guide them.